# postgresql functions - execute 'create table...' - unexpected results

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql, execute, dynamic-sql

I'm writing a function which does the following:

Create a temporary table with a single field.
This field is the result of the sum of up to 5 variables from a specific table.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
create table src (x1 numeric, x2 numeric);
insert into src values (2,1),(5,2),(10,4);
```

My code is:

```
create or replace function qwert(cod numeric, v1 numeric default 0
    , v2 numeric default 0, v3 numeric default 0, v4 numeric default 0,
    v5 numeric default 0)
returns numeric as
$func$
declare vv numeric;
begin
vv = v1+v2+v3+v4+v5;
execute '
    drop table if exists t' || cod || '; 
    create temporary table t' || cod || ' as 
    select ' || vv || ' ;'
    ;
return vv;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

If I run:
        select qwert(1, x1,x2) from src;

The expected result is a table t1:

```
 column1 
---------
       3
       7
       14
(3 rows)
```

Instead the result is:

```
db1=# select * from t1;
 ?column? 
----------
       14
(1 row)
```

In my code, line:
    return vv;
is only there to check whether vv was being created correctly.

Could someone help you this?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: What do you need the temp table for? Or is that just a (failed) attempt to get a set of rows from the function? Also, your question still doesn't add up. Do you want to sum `x1 + x2` from table `src`?

Comment: I need a temp table to store new variables which I need to use in further calculations. In each session my input variables may change. I want to sum up to five columns, therefore I set default values to zero. As an example, I'm just trying to sum two columns (x1 and x2 from src). the resulting table should have x1+x2 (3,7,14). Big sorry. My query should be: select qwert(1, x1,x2) from src; (hence the confusion, I think...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qwert(_tbl text, cols text[])
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %1$I;
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE %1$I AS 
     SELECT %2$s AS col_sum FROM src;'
   ,_tbl
   ,(SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(i), ' + ') FROM unnest(cols) i)
    );

RETURN 1;  -- still unclear? Add yourself ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Call:

```
SELECT qwert('t1', ARRAY['x1','x2']);
```

Or:

```
SELECT qwert('t1', '{x1,x2}');
```

`format()` requires Postgres 9.1 or later.

I use a `text` parameters for the temp table name and an `array of text` for the column names, then build the expression with a combination of [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html). Don't forget to name the column (`col_sum` in my ex.).

Details about [sanitizing *values* for use as *identifiers* in this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718). You can pass any number of columns this way.

Comment: I run your code and the result is a table whose values are 10,4,0,0,0. I think my question wasn't clear. I edited just now. Thanks.

Comment: My table must be the result of a select query. The real table I'm working with has thousands of records.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004980/what-is-the-order-between-parsing-and-execution-of-pl-pgsql-functions