# Why can PL/pgSQL functions have side effect, while SQL functions can't?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

[PostgreSQL document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) says:

> **The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is executed.** While a SQL function can contain **commands that alter the
>   system catalogs** (e.g., `CREATE TABLE`), the effects of such commands
>   will not be visible during parse analysis of later commands in the
>   function. Thus, for example,  `CREATE TABLE foo (...); INSERT INTO foo VALUES(...);`
>   **will not work as desired if packaged up into a single
>   SQL function**, since foo  won't exist yet when the `INSERT` command is parsed.
>
> **It's recommended to use PL/pgSQL instead of a SQL function
>   in this type of situation.**

- Why "It's recommended to use PL/pgSQL instead of a SQL function in this type of situation", where the PL/pgSQL or SQL function contains commands that alter the system catalogs, such as `CREATE TABLE foo (...); INSERT INTO foo VALUES(...);` ?
- "The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is executed". Is it not true for a PL/pgSQL function?  What differences are between SQL functions and PL/pgSQL functions, in terms of parsing and executing the commands in their bodies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bolded the [key sentence in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) yourself:

> **The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is executed.**

Also read about [**The Parser Stage** in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parser-stage.html).

It consists of two major parts: the *parser* and the *transformation process*. [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parser-stage.html#id-1.10.3.6.4)

> the *transformation process* takes the tree handed back by the parser as
> input and does the semantic interpretation needed to understand which
> tables, functions, and operators are referenced by the query.

If an SQL function contains these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (...);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(...);
```

Both statements are planned at virtually the same time (based on the same snapshot of the system catalogs). Hence, the `INSERT` cannot see the table "foo" presumably created with the previous `CREATE` command. That creates **one of the following problems**:

1. If there is no *other* table named "foo" [in your `search_patch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777) (yet), Postgres complains **when trying to create** the function:

   > ```
   > ERROR:  relation "foo" does not exist
   > ```
2. If another table named "foo" already exists in your `search_patch` (and you don't use conflicting column names), Postgres will plan the `INSERT` based on that pre-existing table. Typically that results in an error **at execution time**, if any values cause conflicts in the (wrong!) table. Or, with some bad luck, it might even write to that table without error message! Very sneaky bug.

That cannot happen with a **PL/pgSQL** function, because it treats SQL commands like prepared statements, planned and executed ***sequentially***. So each statement can see objects created in previous statements.

Consequently, statements that are never visited are never even planned - unlike with SQL functions. And the execution plan for statements can be cached within the same session - also unlike SQL functions. [Read details about plan caching in PL/pgSQL functions in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)
Each approach has advantages for some use cases. Further reading:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561?noredirect=1#comment89024896_24771561)

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052885/what-is-the-difference-between-a-prepared-statement-and-a-sql-or-pl-pgsql-functi

Comment: "the execution plan for statements can be cached within the same session - also unlike SQL functions. " What is it like for any SQL function, for example, is the plan for the SQL function ever cached? If yes, cached for the current session?

Comment: @Ben: Unlike prepared statements and PL/pgSQL functions, SQL functions have no mechanisms for plan caching. Plan caching is *always* for the current session exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Plpgsql functions are parsed and syntax-checked at definition time, then at first execution a plan is generated.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING

then that plan is executed with the given parameters.

Temporary files seem to work as expected, except those that already exist on the first execution.

As mentioned in there use of dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) is a way to foil the planner allowing access to arbitrary tables.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks. What differences are between SQL functions and PL/pgSQL functions, in terms of parsing and execution?

Comment: everything. `PLPGSQL`is a procedural language constructed out of SQL statements (and plpgsql keywords). so in PLPGSQL execution order can be variable.  `SQL` only has fixed execution order.

Comment: Could you explain what " It's recommended to use PL/pgSQL instead of a SQL function in this type of situation." means

Comment: PLPGSQL allows you to create and use temp tables in the same function SQL does not. PLPGSQL is the Postgres developer's preferred procedural extension language. so that's the one they recommend.

Comment: I updated my post and hopefully clarified my questions to you. Thanks.

Comment: From the document:"The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is executed." and from your reply: "Plpgsql functions are parsed and syntax-checked at definition time, then at first execution a plan is generated." What is the difference between them?

Comment: there's an initial syntax check when they are defined, there's another parse when thet are executed...

Comment: Thanks. Could you update your reply, and be more specific about that and explicitly point out the differences between a SQL function and a PL/pgSQL function?