# What is the difference between prepared statements and SQL or PL/pgSQL functions, in terms of their purpose?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, plpgsql, sql-function

In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a prepared statement and a SQL or PL/pgSQL function, in terms of their purposes, advantages and disadvantages? When shall we use which?

In this very simple example, do they work the same, correct?

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, name VARCHAR(80)); 

CREATE FUNCTION myfunc1(INT, VARCHAR(80)) RETURNS void AS ' 
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ($1, $2);
' LANGUAGE SQL; 

SELECT myfunc1(3, 'ben');

CREATE FUNCTION myfunc2(INT, VARCHAR(80)) RETURNS void AS ' 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ($1, $2);
END' LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

SELECT myfunc2(3, 'ben');

PREPARE fooplan (INT, VARCHAR(80)) AS
    INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2);
PREPARE

EXECUTE fooplan(3, 'ben');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All three "work the same" in that they execute the simple SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3, 'ben');
```

The prepared statement is only good for a *single* prepared SQL statement (as the name suggests). And only DML commands. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html)

> Any `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `VALUES` statement.

The function can contain any number of statements. DML *and* DDL. Only SQL for SQL functions. Plus some non-SQL procedural elements in PL/pgSQL.

The prepared statement is only visible inside the same session and gone at the end of the session, while the function persists and is visible to all - still only usable for those with the `EXECUTE` privilege.

The prepared statement is encumbered with the least overhead. (Not much difference.)

The SQL function is the only one of the three that cannot save the query plan (by itself). [Read details about plan caching in PL/pgSQL functions in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)

The SQL function is also the only one that could be [***inlined***](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) when used within a bigger query. (Not with an `INSERT`, though.)

A rather comprehensive list of differences between SQL and PL/pgSQL functions:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Starting with Postgres 11 there are also SQL procedures:

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)

Comment: Thanks. What does "SQL functions cannot save the query plan (by itself)" mean?

Comment: @Ben: Prepared statements save the query plan for repeated execution within the same session. PL/pgSQL functions treat statements effectively as prepared statements. SQL functions do not. But the query plan might still be saved indirectly when the SQL function is used in a query for which the plan is saved.

Comment: Thanks. PostgreSQL document says that "**When the  PREPARE  statement is executed**, the specified statement is **parsed**, **analyzed**, and **rewritten**. **When an  EXECUTE  command is subsequently issued**, the prepared statement is **planned** and **executed**. This division of labor avoids repetitive parse analysis work, while allowing the
execution plan to depend on the specific parameter values supplied." Similarly, what is it like for defining a SQL function and for calling the SQL function with some argument(s)?

Comment: Also what does "inlined" in a bigger query mean for a SQL function?

Comment: More details in the linked answer I provided above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561