# In parametrized PostgreSQL query, is it possible to name the parameters somehow at the beginning for easier reuse?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a parametrized query that filters a table based on parameters most of which are optional. By optional I mean the `WHERE` part looks kinda like this:

```
    (
        -- Here I am allowing search by one or multiple text values on the "text_column"
        -- but if zero values are put into the query, "text_column" does not filter results
        array_length(cast($1 as text[]), 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY(cast($1 as text[]))
    )
    and
    (
        -- Either looking for an exact enum value or not filtering by this column
        cast($2 as custom_enum_type) is null or
        column_with_enum = $2
    )
    and
    (
        -- Filtering by some floating point value or ignoring this column
        cast($3 as float8) is null or
        floating_point_column >= $3
    )
```

There's currently 11 of these, and some are more complicated meaning the `$X` param gets mentioned multiple times. The `cast($x as type)` seems to be required because otherwise the library I am using will fail because it cannot deduce the type that should be used for that parameter.

Now I'd prefer something like this before the query:

```
expected_text = cast($1 as text[])
```

Then do:

```
    (
        array_length(expected_text, 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY(expected_text)
    )
```

This would make it much easier to edit the query. The only thing I did think of doesn't really work, which was `select ... as` to make fake result columns and use those in my query:

```
SELECT
   ... some columns ...,
   cast($1 as text[]) as __text_column_options
WHERE
    (
        array_length(__text_column_options, 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY(__text_column_options)
    )
    and
    ... other options ...
```

But I get an error:

```
error: column "__text_column_options" does not exist
```

Even if this worked it wouldn't be so nice, since I'd getting my parameters back in the results.

Note that I have only read only access to the DB, so I cannot create a stored procedure or something like that.

Comment: Have you considered creating a function out of your query? You can write custom functions in pure SQL as well as pl/pgsql and that allows proper parameter naming

Comment: If you're referring to a [prepared statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html), then you can usually rebuild it as [a routine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) with [little to no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51052885/5298879) in performance, tons of benefit in usability and flexibility.

Comment: I don't have write access to the DB, so I cannot store any stored statements or functions or anything like that. If possible, I want it to be a single text file that my program loads, sets the parameters and executes.

Comment: Are you coding this in PL/pgSQL, or are you using a prepared statement? Why don't you force the input parameters to the correct type?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am not sure if I know the answer to this. I am using this as a postgresql query that I load from a file and execute from within some program I wrote. The library I use seems to require to be able to infer the parameter types from the query.

Comment: Where do the parameters come from? What programming language? Please show more of the code. I cannot make a suggestion without knowing what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a [prepared statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html), then you can usually rebuild it as [a (temp) routine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) with [little to no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51052885/5298879) in performance, tons of benefit in usability and flexibility.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/5JCiAFYo)

```
create table some_table(id serial, text_column text);
insert into some_table(text_column) values ('a'),('b'),('c');
```

```
create function pg_temp.my_statement_as_function(__text_column_options text[])
returns setof some_table as $f$
select id,text_column
from some_table
where ( array_length(__text_column_options, 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY(__text_column_options) );
$f$ language sql ;

select * from pg_temp.my_statement_as_function('{a,b}')
```

| id | text_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

That being said, your trick could work:

```
prepare my_statement(text) as 
with my_params as (select cast($1 as text[]) as __text_column_options)
select id,text_column
from some_table, my_params 
where ( array_length(__text_column_options, 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY(__text_column_options) );

execute my_statement('{a,b}');
```

| id | text_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

You should also be able to use `text[]` in statement signature directly, removing the need to cast:

```
deallocate my_statement;
prepare my_statement(text[]) as 
select id,text_column
from some_table
where ( array_length($1, 1) = 0 or
        text_column = ANY($1) );

execute my_statement('{a,b}');
```

| id | text_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

If you want a `declare` statement, you'll need [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html):

```
drop function pg_temp.my_statement_as_function(text[]);
create function pg_temp.my_statement_as_function(__text_column_options text)
returns setof some_table as $f$
declare 
  __text_column_options_as_array text[] := __text_column_options::text[];
begin
  return query 
    select id,text_column
    from some_table
    where ( array_length(__text_column_options_as_array, 1) = 0 or
            text_column = ANY(__text_column_options_as_array) );
end $f$ language plpgsql ;

select * from pg_temp.my_statement_as_function('{a,b}')
```

| id | text_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |