# Can I create and access a table in the same SQL function?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to create a Postgres SQL-function which runs some routine for my database.

The SQL-function calls a plpgsql-function which creates several temporary tables, but doesn't return anything (`RETURNS void`).
One of the tables created by the plpgsql-function is supposed to be used in my sql-function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_sql_function()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

select public.my_plpsql_function(); -- this returns void, but has created a temp table "tmp_tbl"

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  skov_id int8 PRIMARY KEY,
  skov_stor int4,
  skov_areal_ha numeric,
  virkningfra timestamp(0) without time zone,
  plannoejagtighed float8,
  vertikalnoejagtighed float8,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,25832),
  orig_geom geometry(Polygon, 25832) 
);

INSERT INTO mytable
select * from tmp_tbl ....

$BODY$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

When I try to run the lines, I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: relation "tmp_tbl" does not exist
> ```

pgAdmin underlines the line `select * from tmp_tbl ...` as the part with an error.

So the SQL-function doesn't notice that the plpsql-function has created a temporary table.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: It's probably just pgAdmin's source code parser. Does it work when you run it? But why a temp table to begin with? More often than not, a solution without temp tables is faster in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so it is not possible - and minimally it should not by possible in future versions. SQL functions are similar to views, and then references to database object should be valid in function's creating time.

There is not any workaround - if you need temp table, use PLpgSQL, or try to write your code without temp table (it can be much better).

Comment: I accept this as the answer, as i expected my code needed to be rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

Creating ***and*** accessing a table in the same SQL function is generally impossible. Makes no difference whether you create the table in the SQL function directly or in a nested function call. All objects must be visible to begin with.

There is a big, fat note at the top of the chapter [***Query Language (SQL) Functions***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) in the manual pointing that out:

> **Note**
>
> The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is
> executed. While a SQL function can contain commands that alter the
> system catalogs (e.g., `CREATE TABLE`), the effects of such commands
> will not be visible during parse analysis of later commands in the
> function. Thus, for example, `CREATE TABLE foo (...); INSERT INTO foo VALUES(...);` will not work as desired if packaged up into a single
> SQL function, since foo won't exist yet when the `INSERT` command is
> parsed. It's recommended to use PL/pgSQL instead of a SQL function in
> this type of situation.

Related:

- [Why can PL/pgSQL functions have side effect, while SQL functions can't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004980/why-can-pl-pgsql-functions-have-side-effect-while-sql-functions-cant/51033884#51033884)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)